# .Net Core SignOut() RedirectUri not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm trying to do a SignOut with a `redirect uri` specified in the `AuthenticationProperties`. It redirects to the OIDC SignedOutCallbackPath I configured but doesn't make it to the RedirectURI.

```
    [HttpGet("Logout")]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        var prop = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            RedirectUri = "http://google.com"
        };

        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, prop);
    }
```

Setup and info:

- The app has Cookie and OpenId Connect authentication setup
- Connects to Oracle IDCS.
- Both HttpContext.SignOutAsync() and SignOut() have the same result.
- `A login via ChallengeRequest with a RedirectUri on the other hand works.`

How does the Redirect URI actually work inside - ex. does it get sent to the Identity Provider and back? Any clues as to why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it the redirection didn't work when I set the OIDC SignedOutCallbackPath to signout-oidc.

See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28009.